# FMDB open database

Tags: fmdb

I'm trying to open a database that I have in my project inside Resources.

The problem is that it seems that its impossible to find the database file!
I tried with the complete path, and it works, but this is not a good solution.

I would like to now how to open it!

I'm using this code:
db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"bbdd.sql"];

I don't know how to find the other part of the "actual" path.

Do you have a solution for me?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 8):

You need to find the full path of the database in the your resource bundle, something like this :

```
NSString *databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mySQLiteDatabaseFile" ofType:@"sqlite3"];
```

There's a complete example in this thread [Copying data to the Application Data folder on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170740/copying-data-to-the-application-data-folder-on-the-iphone)

Comment: But I still have a problem it opens this long address the path it opens is:
/Users/nameOfUser/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.2/Applications/5399D73E-F31A-46B1-94B1-EAD3E2B96D6E/appName.app/bbdd.sql
And the path that I need is:
/Users/nameOfUser/Folder1/Folder2/appName/bbdd.sql

I need to know how to get the path of the folder where the project is to open the database.

Comment: The "long address path" is because you're running in the simulator. And it looks like the path is correct for a bundle supplied sql file. If you want to edit it, you now need to copy it to the Applications Document directory (see link in my original comment)

Answer (score 4):

Get Document directory:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dbPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test.db"];
```

Next

```
DB = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath：dbPath];
```

Comment: I had the problem also with the database path, not pointing to document directory. Good idea.