# Monotouch - Attach Sqlite database in monotouch project and deploy to iPad

Tags: iphone, database, ipad, sqlite, xamarin.ios

All the code samples I found so far regarding using a Sqlite database in an iPad/iPhone app use scripts to create the database once the app is deployed.

But is it possible to create a database in monotouch, build the structure, even pre-populate it with data and deploy it along with iPad app?

If so, what is the location of the database, How do I build the Sqlite Connection?
At the moment I use the following:

```
new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + DatabasePath);
```

Where

```
public static String DatabasePath {
    get {
        string documents = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        return Path.Combine (documents, "MyDB.db");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pre-build your database, [copy it into the app bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170740/copying-data-to-the-application-data-folder-on-the-iphone), and (as long as it is read-only) you could access it directly from your app's bundle whenever you want.  If you need write access you could copy your pre-built file to a [different directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551065/core-data-and-itunes-file-sharing-move-hide-the-sqlite-file-on-app-update/4551544#4551544) and then modify it from there.

Comment: +1 - I'm doing exactly this in a project now and it works perfectly.

Comment: Ok fair enough. I don't quite like the fact to have to move it to write to the db, but I guess that's the way it is.

Comment: What's the best location to put it into to write to the db?

Comment: I'd put it in the library directory myself, unless you want the user to ahve access, then in the documents directory.

Answer (score 2):

For people using Monotouch, this is how I sorted this issue:

1. Created the Sqlite database with sqliteman
2. In monodevelop, right-click on the Project > Add > Add Files
3. Choose the sqlite db created and click Open
4. Click on Copy on the warning dialog
5. Right click on the database you've just added > Build Action > Content

Then all you have to do is to create a simple method to copy the database to a destination folder, like Documents:

```
public static void CopyDatabase(String destinationPath)
{
    String path = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("MyDB", "db");
    File.Copy(path, destinationPath);
}
```

Where destinationPath in my case is the path specified above in the question: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6157267/764205)
. Obviously, in production you'd have to have some sort of mechanism to check whether the db does not already exists, so that you don't overwrite the database file.

Hope it helps.